# Using SQL Select Where to set ComboBox Rowsource

Tags: mysql, ms-access, combobox, vba

I'm trying to use multiple combobox selections to filter the records that are displayed in a final combobox.  It works fine if I use Select Where, but as soon as I add an AND to the statement, it returns no records.  I don't get any errors.  Just no results and have verified that results should populate.  For now, i have removed the combobox variables (me.combobox.value) and i put the values right into the code to simplify and try to get it working (e.g. General Electric and Stage 1 Turbine Blade).  The first code set works fine with only a WHERE clause.  The second does NOT work because i inserted an AND clause.  Can anyone tell me why this does not return results?

```
Private Sub cboConfiguration_AfterUpdate()

On Error Resume Next
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strComponent As String
Dim strOEM As String
Dim strScope As String
Dim strConfig As String

strScope = Me!cboScope.Value
strConfig = Me!cboConfiguration.Value

'this one will work
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_WORKSCOPES " & _
     "WHERE OEM = " & " 'General Electric'"

'this one returns no results
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_WORKSCOPES " & _
     "WHERE OEM = " & " 'General Electric' AND Components = " & " 'Stage 1 Turbine Blade'"

Me.cboTables.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.cboTables.RowSource = strSQL
Me.cboTables.Requery
Me.cboTables.Enabled = True
Me.cboTables.SetFocus
Me.cboTables.Dropdown

End Sub
```

Comment: You said that you verified that results should populate. Does that mean you ran the same SQL and it returned records?

Comment: How many records does Access find when you paste the same `SELECT` statement into SQL View of a new Access query and run it there? `SELECT * FROM MASTER_WORKSCOPES WHERE OEM =  'General Electric' AND Components =  'Stage 1 Turbine Blade'`

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried to change the AND keyword to OR? My hunch is there aren't any rows that have both columns equal to those values at the same time. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your dynamic SQL.